# looking for the EasySDX v0.98b

Tags: tcl

Does anyone know how to download the EasySDX v0.98b small frontend for sdx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://www.magicsplat.com/blog/tags/tclkit/index.html) is a complete guide to build an executable by Ashok P. Nadkarni using tclkits.

Other useful resources are [tcl wiki](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org) and [tcl lang group](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.tcl).

Saludos,

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about ezsdx, but if you just want to convert a Tcl/Tk script into a standalone executable, an easy alternative is http://www.ch-werner.de/cgi-bin/luck.pl  . To wrap a script that uses Tk to run on 64-bit Windows, start by selecting `vanillawish-win64.exe`.